# how to define an architecture for a database deployment

Tags: mysql, database, architecture

Hy.

I'm building a software and then I deploy the sources on to 3 differents mysql databases (hosted on 3 differents places), my question is... is there a way to automatize changes I made in one of the db to the others???

Is there any tool I can use so I do not have to change manually all the databases???

Comment: I am afraid that question is off topic

Comment: Are you asking about [schema migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration)?

Comment: mmm not precisely, Im asking about continuous deployment, when you are developing some on a development enviroment you work on a development db isn't? so when you test it you do it on a test enviroment with a test db, so what i need to do is to reflect the latest changes on development db over test db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an automated job execution, you must create a scripting tools yourself and execute as your need. But what I see now is you need some way of [Database Versioning](http://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/).

It's hard to understand at first but it's easy enough to dig it down. The versioning process is:

1. baseline: This is your entire database tables and predefined records in one script. Usually it is recorded on major version such as 1.0.0.sql or 2.0.0.sql. Baseline only executed once.
2. updates: this is a "patch" for your tables separated in each sql scripts.
3. view, functions and procedures: each of your views, functions and procedures in separated sql file.
4. schema_change_log: this table records baseline version and updates patch versions executed in database

The publishing step:

1. check latest version in schema_change_log
2. get updates with version bigger than the latest version
3. execute the updates script
4. drop all views, functions and procedures
5. re-apply all views, functions and procedures

Answer (score 0):

I recommend for this to use [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) so you can make any changes to the model and then through the menu of Database you can synchronize the changes with your databases.

Comment: that's a great solution when it comes to a schema or a complete db but when it comes to certain data or certain column over a table of a db isn't that good